# Installing Apache/PHP/MySQL on Mac - Restoring Configurations?

Tags: mysql, macos, apache

so I've been naively playing around with the Apache settings following several different tutorials. It's come to a point where nothing is working. Is there a simple way where I can restore these configuration settings to those that came with the Mac when I bought it. In other words, can I go back to the original settings and work my way up from there again, this time with all the experience I have gained messing around with it?

Thanks

Comment: Time Machine backup or OSX Reinstall are your only two options. [Next time try using MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/)

Comment: "Not working" is not a diagnostic error. To restore to the factory defaults you can always reinstall the operating system to be sure. You may also be able to copy a pristine Apache `httpd` configuration file from another installation.

Comment: @sjagr OS X ships with Apache httpd by default. That's how it serves pages with Web Sharing. MAMP is also awful compared to Homebrew, it's extremely limited in comparison.

Comment: @tadman Yikes. If the httpd it came with already served a purpose, it shouldn't have been messed with...

Comment: Unless you make use of the default web sharing you can usually modify the configuration file to do whatever you want with it instead. It's not a big deal if done carefully. As always, having a Time Machine back-up of the "before" state is a great idea. Another trick is to create a local `git` repo of `/etc` to be able to view and undo any changes made.

Comment: @tadman Well, to be specific, I can't create phpinfo.php file in my Sites directory through the 'sudo nano' command all tutorials tell me to make to verify my php is working. At this point I think it would be easier to do a fresh install of the OS.

Comment: If it's not too much of a hassle to reinstall, then sure. Otherwise you can disable the built-in server (turn off Web Sharing in System Preferences) and install the [Homebrew one](http://brew.sh/) which can be reinstalled any time if you mess it up, all independent of your OS.

Answer (score 2):

You can try copy files from /etc/apache2/original/ to actual config and restart apache.

Comment: I was afraid this was going to be the answer, So I have to rebuild my custom development environment... kill me now.